# Getting error when trying to fetch object from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

So this is my code:

```
 <?php

    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT products.name,
        categories.name AS 'category',
        products.id AS 'prod_id',
        FROM products
        LEFT JOIN categories
        ON products.category = categories.id");
?>
    <h1>Products</h1>
    <table width="500" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="" border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>ID#</th>
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>Category</th>
        </tr>

            <?php while ($row = $result->fetch_object()): ?>
           <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row->prod_id;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row->name;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row->category;?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </table>
```

When reloading the page I get this error message back:
"Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_object() on boolean in...".

Any idea what could be wrong? 
Thanks in forehand!

Comment: You'll probably want to print `$mysqli->error()` if `$result` is false (ie something goes wrong with the query)

Comment: As to your actual error, seems to be a simple typo with an extra comma. Removing the comma before `FROM` should fix the query, which `$mysqli->error` most likely would show.